# Nunit result xml is not updated during Jenkins build

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, nunit-console

I have configured NUnit tests to run after build completed.(Jenkins)

### I added following on Excecute windows batch command window in Jenkins.

rmdir ClickOnceInstall /Q /S

mkdir ClickOnceInstall

CD BuildScripts

Start.bat

### "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe" AA.Tests\bin\x86\Release\AA.Tests.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml

It seems Execute unit test command doesn't create result file as specified name and marked as failed. However, when I run the nunit test command manually it creates the file. Next time build through Jenkins, result xml file does not seem to be updated but it doesn't fail.

am I missing any configuration or something else?

Comment: The xml file will be in the current working directory when NUnit is invoked.  Have you checked that directory.  (Batch files may cd for you, so check start.bat.)  Also, does the console output give any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you would paste the console log.

However, my first guess is to ask you to add `call` to your batch file statement:
`call Start.bat`

If that batch file has an `exit /b` statement (even with `0`), it will quit the whole calling step (i.e. "Execute windows batch command") without getting to your last statement (i.e nunit command).

Using `call` in front of the batch file will make sure that control is returned to the calling step.

Comment: Yes. That could be the issue. I added call Start.bat as you mentioned. However it still seems to be skip the Execute windows batch command.

Comment: @chenk Please paste the console output if further debugging needed

Comment: Nothing recorded in the console output since it looks like console-runner not calling and as you said it exit after start.bat finishes.

Comment: Please change the whole line to `call Start.bat && echo success || echo failed`. You should see at least either of the echos. Once again, please paste the console out (edit the original question). It may have clues that we are not seeing.

Comment: The issue was found. somewhere in the inner batch file 'Exit' command used that made the control to skip the calling step and exit. After replacing as 'EXIT /B 0', it works as expected. Thank you very much for your ideas which help me to sorted this issue out.